# Can't seem to create recursive algorithm for wallless maze

Tags: python, recursion, maze

I've been working on this for a while, this is what I've got so far... this code doesn't work. This code is just for reference. The assignment is a maze without walls. I have to use a recursive algorithm.  Each space has a number, when I land on a space, that number tells me how much I can move in a specific direction. I have to return the path. (I already did the version where I return True or False if there is a solution.) I can't seem to return the path itself.

```
def pathsolve(self, start, end, vis=None):


    z=self.__getitem__(start)
    x,y=start




    b=False

    if path==None:
        path=deque()

    if vis==None:
        vis=deque()

    if start == end:
        vis.appendleft(start)
        return True
    elif start in path:
        return False
    elif z==0:
        return False
    else:
        #visited.add(start)
        path.append(start)


        if self.onboard((x+z,y)) and (x+z,y) not in path:
            #print("going to"+str((x+z,y))+" by "+str(z)+" from "+str    (start))
            b=self.pathsolve((x+z,y),end, path)

            #print()
        if self.onboard((x,y+z)) and (x,y+z) not in path and b == False:
            #print("xgoing to"+str((x,y+z))+" by "+str(z)+" from "+str(start))
            b=self.pathsolve((x,y+z),end, path)

            #print()
        if self.onboard((x,y-z)) and (x,y-z) not in path and b == False:
            #print("ygoing to"+str((x,y-z))+" by "+str(z)+" from "+str(start))
            #print(self.onboard((x,y-z)))
            b=self.pathsolve((x,y-z),end, path)
            #print(path)
        if self.onboard((x-z,y)) and (x-z,y) not in path and b == False:
            #print("zgoing to"+str((x-z,y))+" by "+str(z)+" from "+str(start))
            #print(end)
            b=self.pathsolve((x-z,y),end, path)

       # if b==True and start is not  
            vis.appendleft(start)
    return b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things to note:

- contrary to how `vis` is passed as argument and needs to maintain its state throughout the recursive search, this is not how `path` should work: it should be a local variable that only takes the return value from the recursive call and prepends the current cell (`start`) to it.
- `vis` should not be a `deque`, but a `set`, which is more suitable for quickly knowing whether a cell was visited before.

Here is how you could code it:

```
def pathsolve(self, start, end, vis=set()):
    z=self.__getitem__(start)
    x,y=start
    if start == end:
        return [end]
    if start in vis or z==0:
        return None
    vis.add(start)
    for step in [(x+z,y),(x-z,y),(x,y+z),(x,y-z)]:
        if self.onboard(step):
            path=self.pathsolve(step, end, vis)
            if path: # prepend current cell to the path that was found
                return [start] + path
    return None # None of the possible directions led to the end point.
```

This assumes of course that your other methods are well implemented.

See it run on [repl.it](https://repl.it/@trincottrincots/MazeWithoutWalls).

For the following maze:

```
[
    [1,1,2,0,0],
    [3,1,0,1,3],
    [1,0,2,0,2]
]
```

...and starting at the lower-left corner, targetting the top-right corner, it gives this path of (x, y) coordinates (x = column, y = row):

```
[(0, 2), (0, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0), (2, 0), (4, 0)]
```